A media query doesn't behave the same way on Android and iPhone
Whatever I put between the filter and the background, there still is no background at all when opening the burger menu on an iPhone 13.
.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter:blur 30px OR background: #111111; 
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 130px;
    transition: all .5s ease;

}
I have a Samsung S9 and it works with both, also my gf has tried it with her Xiaomi phone and it works too. Must be the iOS and Android differences.
How do I approach the problem ? What should I change?
